# An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)

Tags: ssis

I have an Execute SQL task that has this query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [table]
INSERT INTO [table]
EXEC usp_populate ?, ? , ?
```

I have the  third ? is the only one giving me this error.
insert int..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I tried to change the variable data type to Int, float, string but that didn't help.

here's a screenshot of my Parameter Mapping setup. Is there anything that I'm missing?
[image]

Comment: Make sure User::Period only has Int32 data in it.   Setting that dropdown isn't enough to ensure that.   Adjust at the Data type in the variables window for Period to Int32 and fix it up before it gets to this step.

Comment: Unfortunately that still gave me the same error.

Comment: Int32 is the correct way into DBTYPE_I4.  Other thoughts:  Are you positive it's the third ?  Are you by chance using odbc?  The [parameter name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#parameters-in-the-execute-sql-task) starts at 1 for odbc, and must be named for ado.

Comment: I hard coded the other two ? and it worked fine! Thanks to you now I know its the other two variables.